# use tablesoter using date format ddd d MMM

Tags: javascript, asp.net, tablesorter

I am trying to use TableSorter in my asp.net application but this not working with my format.
If forced my columns as shortDate and i want to edit this parser to work with my format

---

### code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            // initialize stickyTableHeaders _after_ tablesorter
            $(".tablesorter").tablesorter(
           { headers:
          {
              3: { sorter: "shortDate" },
              4: { sorter: "shortDate" },

              5: { sorter: "usLongDate" },
              6: { sorter: "shortDate" },
              7: { sorter: "shortDate" },
              8: { sorter: "shortDate" },
              9: { sorter: "shortDate" }

         }

       });
        $("table").stickyTableHeaders();
       });
```

---

my parser code:

---

```
  ts.addParser({
    id: "shortDate",
    is: function (s) {
        return /\d{1,2}[\/\-]\d{1,2}[\/\-]\d{2,4}/.test(s);
    }, format: function (s, table) {
        var c = table.config;
 
        
        s = s.replace(/\-/g, "/");
        if (c.dateFormat == "us") {
            // reformat the string in ISO format
            s = s.replace(/(\d{1,2})[\/\-](\d{1,2})[\/\-](\d{4})/, "$3/$1/$2");
        } else if (c.dateFormat == "uk") {
            // reformat the string in ISO format
            s = s.replace(/(\d{1,2})[\/\-](\d{1,2})[\/\-](\d{4})/, "$3/$2/$1");
        } else {
            s = s.replace(".", "");

            // s1 = s.replace(/(\d{1,2})[\/\-](\d{1,2})[\/\-](\d{2})/, "$1/$2/$3");
           var s1 = s.substr(3);
          
        }
        return $.tablesorter.formatFloat(new Date(s1).getTime());
    }, type: "numeric"
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer:

```
 monthDict = {
    'janv': '01', 'févr': '02', 'mars': '03',
    'avr': '04', 'mai': '05', 'juin': '06',
    'juil': '07', 'août': '08', 'sept': '09',
    'oct': '10', 'nov': '11', 'déc': '12'
}

   ts.addParser({
    id: "shortDate",
    is: function (s, table, cell) { return false; },
format: function (s, table, cell, cellIndex) {

    var dat = s.split('.');
    var dates = dat[1].trim().split(' ');
    dat[0] = (/^\d{2}$/.test(dates[0])) ? dates[0] : '0' + dates[0];
    return monthDict[dates[1]]+dat[0] 

},
type: "numeric"
});
```